# Angular Jest mock subscribe content

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

How do we mock the content which is consumed by the subscribe method..I am able to initialize the testService but struggling to mock the content of subscribe

```
export class AppComponent {


constructor(){}



     CheckTestLink(link: any) {
     this.testService.init().subscribe( configUsers => {
            const conf: [] = configUsers['entries'].filter( entry =>
              (this.userName === entry.content.properties.user_name );
            if (conf.length > 0) {
 
             
            } else {
 
             
            }
          },
          errors => {
  
            this.ErrorService.notifyError('Error fetching details.');
          });
  }
    }
```

AppComponent

```
    describe( 'AppComponent', () => {
    let fixture: AppComponent;
     let TestServiceMOck;

beforeEach( () => {
    TestServiceMOck={
     init:jest.fn().mockImplementation(subscribe=>{return of('test')})
      }

    fixture = new AppComponent(
        
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TestServiceMOck={
     init:jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of({ entries: [{ 
           content: { properties : { user_name: 'hola' } } }] }))
      }
```

You shouldn't mock the `subscribe`, it will come if you return an `observable` from the method.

Edit =======
For the error, you have to do this:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
....
TestServiceMOck={
     init:jest.fn().mockReturnValue(throwError({}))
      }
```

Comment: Got it..but how do I mock this part  .subscribe( configUsers => {
            const conf: [] = configUsers['entries'].filter( entry =>
              (this.userName === entry.content.properties.user_name );
            if (conf.length > 0) {
 
             
            } else {
 
             
            }
          },
          errors => {
  
            this.ErrorService.notifyError('Error fetching details.');
          });

Comment: You have to mock what's inside of the `of`. Check out my edit.

Comment: Thanks it works..Only the error part is not working . I am trying this       const error: HttpErrorResponse = {
  status: 401,
   message: 'You are not logged in'
 } as HttpErrorResponse;TestServiceMOck={
     init:jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
          throwError(error))
      }